# keep has_each for a list in Specman

Tags: constraints, verification, specman, e

I am trying to create a keep with this functionality:

```
extend sys {
    ListA : list of uint;
    keep ListA.size() == 3; // For the example
    keep for each in ListA { // For the example
        it < 10;
    };
    
    ListB : list of uint;
    keep ListB.size() == 8;
};
```

I want to add a keep "has_each", meaning, I want to ensure that all of the members of ListA are generated in ListB.

One way I know how to do this is the following:

```
    keep for each in ListB {
        read_only(index < ListA.size()) => it == ListA[index];
    };
```

The problem with this method is if I have some form of keep that already sets the first index, for example if I also need the keep:

```
    keep ListB[0] > 10;
```

which in this case would cause a contradiction.

Another idea I tried that didn't work was:

```
keep read_only(ListA) in ListB;
```

Happy to hear any suggestions.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
  keep for each in ListA {
    it in ListB;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I need ListA in a read_only for dependency issues. When I do this I get no generative variable error

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you want ListA to always be generated before ListB?
are there other constraints on ListB, rather than on its size?